# Is it possible to change the metadata of a column that is on a partitioned table in Hive?

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive, cloudera, hive-metastore

This is an extension of a previous question I asked: [Is it possible to change partition metadata in HIVE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58294633/is-it-possible-to-change-partition-metadata-in-hive)

We are exploring the idea of changing the metadata on the table as opposed to performing a CAST operation on the data in SELECT statements. Changing the metadata in the MySQL metastore is easy enough. But, is it possible to have that metadata change applied to a column that is on a partitioned table (they are daily)? Note: the column itself is not the partitioning column. It is a simple ID field that is being changed from STRING to BIGINT.

Otherwise, we might be stuck with current and future data being of type BIGINT while the historical is STRING.

**Question:** Is it possible to change partition meta data in Hive? If yes, how?

Note: I am asking this as a separate question as the original answer appears to be for a column on a partitioned table that is also the partitioning column. So, I do not want to muddy the waters.

**Update:**

I ran the `ALTER TABLE .. CHANGE COLUMN ... CASCADE` command, but I get the following error:

> Error while processing statement: FAILED: Execution Error, return code
>   1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask. Not allowed to alter
>   schema of Avro stored table having external schema. Consider removing
>   avro.schema.literal or avro.schema.url from table properties.

The metadata is stored in a separate avro file. I can confirm that the updated metadata is in the avro file, but not in the individual partition file.

Note: The table is stored as EXTERNAL.

Comment: A sister question is posted here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58334298/hive-error-when-changing-column-metadata-on-partitioned-table-avrotypeexception

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily change column type:

Use alter table in Hive, change type to STRING, etc:

```
alter table table_name change column col_name col_name string cascade; --change to string
```

See [documentation](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DDL#LanguageManualDDL-ChangeColumnName/Type/Position/Comment).

`ALTER TABLE CHANGE COLUMN` with `CASCADE` command changes the columns of a table's metadata, and cascades the same change to all the partition metadata.

Alternatively you can recreate table like in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58299056/2700344

Comment: Yeah I saw `CASCADE` and thought that might be it. I have about 400 partitions, can I run that command and be OK or do I need to run it in batch?

Comment: @JWeezy  It should be OK with cascade. I'm not sure about formats and serde that are schema-containing like Avro, ORC, Parquet. I'm not sure will this method work with such formats. If not, probably the option is to reload data into new table. If you can test it with one of these formats it would be great if you let us know does it works or not. But I believe it should work because the docs says: "Tables that have serdes which self-describe the table schema may have different schemas in reality and the ones stored in Hive Metastore"

Comment: @JWeezy This is exactly what I am trying to say in previous comment. I do not know how to fix Avro. sorry, maybe someone else will help

Comment: @JWeezy what if you  do as suggested? remove avro.schema.literal or avro.schema.url from table properties (recreate external table)

Comment: If I remove the Avro metadata file (`avro.schema.url`) and just create the table, would I need to run the MSCK command and then ALTER COLUMN?

Comment: @JWeezy After recreating external table - yes you need to to recover partitions. Try to do the same using alter table without recreating it

Comment: Will I need to run MSCK in batch?

Comment: @JWeezy try to change properties only ALTER TABLE table_name SET TBLPROPERTIES your_table_properties;

Comment: Do you know what the `your_table_properties` value should be?

Comment: @JWeezy This may help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44260534/2700344