# Is it possible to change an existing column's metadata on an EXTERNAL table that is defined by an AVRO schema file?

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive, cloudera, hive-metastore

This is an extension of a previous question I asked: [Is it possible to change the metadata of a column that is on a partitioned table in Hive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58333567/is-it-possible-to-change-the-metadata-of-a-column-that-is-on-a-partitioned-table)

**Question:** Is it possible to change an **existing** column's metadata on an EXTERNAL table that is defined by an AVRO schema file?

I need to change the column metadata on a table that is both partitioned and stored as EXTERNAL. The column itself is not the partitioning column. The metadata is stored in a separate AVRO file. I can confirm that the updated metadata is in the AVRO file, but not in the individual partitioned file.

In order to change the metadata in the partitioned files, I ran the `ALTER TABLE TableName CHANGE COLUMN ColumnName ColumnName BIGINT CASCADE;` command, but I get the following error:

> Error while processing statement: FAILED: Execution Error, return code
>   1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask. Not allowed to alter
>   schema of Avro stored table having external schema. Consider removing
>   avro.schema.literal or avro.schema.url from table properties.

I went ahead and successfully ran the following command:

`ALTER TABLE TableName UNSET TBLPROPERTIES ('avro.schema.url');`

I then successfully ran the CHANGE COLUMN command:

`ALTER TABLE TableName CHANGE COLUMN ColumnName ColumnName BIGINT CASCADE;`

When I perform a `SELECT` on the table, I still get an error that indicates the metadata does not match between what is in the metastore versus what is in the partition file. I confirmed this by opening the partition data file. So, it appears that the CASCADE option is not applying to the partition.